# How can i change the navigation drawer icon position in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, navigation-drawer

I am making a custom navigation drawer. My navigation drawer task is like this. Please see this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obZDZTUHRWZW44WlU/edit?usp=sharing.

I am little bit new to this topic. Please tell me how can i do this task in android.

Thanks&Regards

Shankar.